# SCCM Console has tree stuructre but no entries

Tags: windows-server-2008, sccm

Running Windows 2008 R2 / SCCM V4 / SQL Server 2008 - Seperate Server.

The Console was workign fine last week.
I Launch the SCCM Console as Domain Admin it is showing no entries.
The Tree looks intact and is repoting as connecting to the Database.
There are no entries in the Users section in the Console.

It looks like a permissions issue somewhere.
Domain Administrator member is a member of SMS Admins.

Comment: To clarify this is SCCM 2007 SP2.
Checked services and all looked started.
The Site Repair wizard stalls.

Comment: You have presumably tried accessing SCCM using a different user account on a different PC, and checking permissions setup from there?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the SCCM console.  Check to make sure that the console is the same version as the server.  We had applied a SCCM service pack to the server, and forgot to apply it to the console too!  That fixed our problem.